# File to an Array then toal the numbers in the file

Tags: c#

I am trying to total the numbers in the file. I am very new and do not understand how to do this. This is what I have so far. This wants me to explain further but I'm not sure what else to put down. All I know is I have a file that I out into an array. The numbers in the file need to add up in a text box. SOLVED.....I added a for loop and that solved the problem.

Here is the code.

```
    private void totalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            const int SIZE = 7;
            double[] numbers = new double [SIZE];
            double total = 0;
            int index = 0;

            StreamReader inputFile;

            inputFile = File.OpenText("Sales.txt");


                while (index < numbers.Length && !inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    numbers[index] = double.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                    index++;
                }
                for (index = 0; index < numbers.Length; index++)
                {
                    total += numbers[index];
                    totalTextBox.Text = total.ToString();
                }
            inputFile.Close();

            foreach (double value in numbers)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(value);

            }

    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean you want the total of all your numbers in the array?

Comment: You already have the numbers coming into the array right? Just tally them in the while statement. Edit - what Francois said.

Comment: I did what Francois said to do but I get a run time error. It says the index is outside the bounds of the array. My new code is above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `while` statement, just add `total += numbers[index];`, then at the end, `myLabel.Text = total.ToString();` ?

And `index` will give you the count of values.

Comment: It says the index is outside the bounds of the array

Comment: Needed to add a for loop. for (index = 0; index < numbers.Length; index++) thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler way using `System.Linq` (and `File.ReadAllLines(String)` so you don't have to use a `while(){}` loop):

```
// read the file in (broken apart by lines) in to an array:
String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("Sales.txt");

// Try parsing them to Double values:
Double[] numbers = lines.Select(line => {
  Double val = 0;
  Double.TryParse(line, out val);
  return val;
});

// Sum then using .Sum
Double total = lines.Sum();
```

References:

- [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)
- [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)
- [`Enumerable.Sum()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734.aspx)